# Matlab while loop issues

Tags: matlab

I have a relatively simple problem but can't find an appropriate solution. I hope that your vast knowledge can help an amateur like me.

So I have these while loops, that are designed to make sure that a certain value/condition is met:

```
lastDayflight = -(10.234*24*60)*rand(1);
timeOfDay = floor(mod(lastDayflight,60*24)/60);
while timeOfDay > 20 || timeOfDay < 9 
    lastDayflight = -(10.234*24*60)*rand(1);
    timeOfDay = floor(mod(lastDayflight,60*24)/60);
end
```

As you can see, the loop keeps iterating until the variable lastDayflight was not during 21 pm and 8 am.

However, the same loop (see below) for the nighttime will never meet its condition and therefore, never ends.

```
lastNightflight = -(40.234*24*60)*rand(1);
timeOfDay = floor(mod(lastNightflight,60*24)/60);
while timeOfDay < 20 || timeOfDay > 9
    lastNightflight = -(40.234*24*60)*rand(1);
    timeOfDay = floor(mod(lastNightflight,60*24)/60);
end
```

How comes the slightly changed but almost same code works for the day but not for the night? For your convenience, both codes can immediately be put into matlabs command window

Comment: I'm pretty positive you want to use the `and` operator in your loop condition not `or` to meet your set conditions.

Comment: try put like this while (timeOfDay < 20 && timeOfDay > 9 )

Comment: Eliel was right, thanks! Next time, try your luck with giving an official answer and not a comment so I can mark your reply as the correct answer :) (so you get more of your deserved points!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `||` by `&&` in your while statement.

Comment: So subtle but so obvious... :D Thx to you, too!